# Game feature in Flash meant to send me to another level, isn't working. Error #1010 A term is undefined?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, function

I have a chunk of code here that should allow me to switch between frame 1 and 2, which are different levels, once the object is reached and the down key is pressed. But It doesn't work... at all. I keep getting error 1010, A Term is undefined and has no Properties (Then the location) But I can't see any problems at all where the problem is located.

```
 } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
    downPressed = true;
    if(player.hitTestObject(back.Other.lockedDoor)){
      //proceed to the next level if the player is touching an open door
      gotoLevel2();
 }
}
}

function gotoLevel2():void{
 back.Other.gotoAndStop(2); //updates door and key
 back.Visuals.gotoAndStop(2); //updates the visuals
 back.Visuals_2.gotoAndStop(2);
 back.Collisions.gotoAndStop(2); //updates the collisions
 scrollX = 0; //resets the player's x position in the new level
 scrollY = 500; //resets the player's y position in the new level

}
```

ANy fixes/ suggestions? Deadline for this project is slowly approaching and i'm getting worried!

Cheers in advance

If anyone is feeling super kind, I can send the file. Teehee!

Comment: Send me the file, or post *all* your code (email in profile - or post the code in `gotoLevel2` function)

Comment: Sending it now, Man of Snow, cheers!

Comment: Sorry Man of Snow, is your email on your profile correct? It has 2 @ symbols in it, it has changed since I last emailed you! Nothing is going through on my emails, do you mind just checking to see if it's correct? :)

Comment: Sorry, remove the first '@'.  Anyways, I got the file, so :)

Comment: I think you should use a switch statement (`switch(e.keyCode)`), not the problem just saying

Comment: Lots of things are undefined; make sure you set instance names of `Visuals`, `Visuals2`, and `Collisions`.  Also, replace `if(player.hitTestObject(back.Other.lockedDoor)){` with `if(player.hitTestObject(back.lockedDoor)){`, because `Other` isn't an instance in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at `if(player.hitTestObject(back.Other.lockedDoor)){`

`Other` isn't defined, so just replace it with `if(player.hitTestObject(back.lockedDoor)){`

(For other users reading this, he sent me the `fla`)

Also because of this, remove `back.Other.gotoAndStop(2);` from the `gotoLevel2` function.  Also, `Visuals`, `Visuals2`, and `Collisions` aren't defined.  Fix or delete that part of the code.

PS

I emailed you the fixed `fla`

Comment: The Visual, Visual_2 etc are defined in the library, within the visual or collision containers. They are the ones that should be defined, they're just really weirdly hidden. I'm following this tutorial, just without the key, ie: The door can be accessed straight away http://as3gametuts.com/2012/04/05/platformer-8/

Comment: @Ryo123987 The door is not in an instance called `others`, it is in an instance called `back`.  You can only test collisions against things that have `Instance Names`, not library items.  I emailed you the fix